# Firestore, query and update with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need a cloud function that triggers automatically once per day and query in my "users" collection where "watched" field is true and update all of them as false. I get "13:26  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token MyFirstRef" this error in my terminal while deploying my function.
I am not familiar with js so can anyone please correct function. Thanks.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { snapshotConstructor } = require("firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.changeWatched = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 24 hours").onRun((context) => {
  const MyFirstRef = admin.firestore().collection("users")
  const queryRef = await MyFirstRef.where("watched", "==", true).get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach( doc => {
      console.log("debug");
      const realId = doc.id
      const MyRef = await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(realId)
      MyRef.update({watched: false})
    })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points to correct in your code:

- You need to return a Promise when all the asynchronous job is completed. See this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details.
- If you use the `await` keyword, you need to declare the function `async`, see [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).
- A `QuerySnapshot` has a [`forEach()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html#forEach) method
- You can get the `DocumentReference` of a doc from the `QuerySnapshot` just by using the [`ref`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html) property.

The following should therefore do the trick:

```
exports.changeWatched = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 24 hours").onRun(async (context) => {  // <== See async
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const batch = db.batch();
    const snapshot = await db.collection("users").where("watched", "==", true).get();

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        batch.update(doc.ref, { watched: false });
    });

    return batch.commit();  // Here we return the Promise returned by commit()

});
```

Note that we use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), which can contain up to 500 operations. In case you need to update more docs in one Cloud Function execution, use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or cut the batch in several batches.

---

`Promise.all()` version:

```
exports.changeWatched = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 24 hours").onRun(async (context) => {  // <== See async
    const db = admin.firestore();

    const snapshot = await db.collection("users").where("watched", "==", true).get();

    return Promise.all(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.delete());
    
});
```

Comment: 7:92  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

Comment: first line starts with exports

Comment: Can you show the exact line corresponding to the error

Comment: exports.changeWatched = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 5 minutes").onRun(async (context) => {

Comment: This line seems correct. It's difficult to say more...

Comment: parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2017,
  },    I think it's about this was missing but after that now it's like : error  This line has a length of 113. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len

Comment: Now it’s done. Working all fine thanks for your help. For the sake of this function :) can you please provide allpromise version of this because this is a freelance project that i do not know how far user count will go.

Comment: Thanks for your effort I am really grateful.